# Add url in Content security policy

Tags: javascript, java, content-security-policy

I added CSP to my project. I call to a external url: http://xx.xx.xx:3002/socket.io

```
response.addHeader(HEADER_NAME, "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; */socket 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'")
```

But in my browers, I'm getting error:

```
/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NNrFFxf

Content security policy: The options for this page have blocked the loading of a resource 
at https://xx.xx.xx.xx:3002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NNrFz_O (default-src).

Content security policy: Unable to process unknown directive '* / socket'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please share more code of the class in which you wrote security policy.

Comment: Yes, you have an error - a semicolon between: `'unsafe-eval'`; `*/socket`. After `;` should be a next directive name. And [*/socket](https://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJxLtDK2qi4GEkppmRVK1n7WxVamVko5qWWpOUrWmVZG1mA55%2BAAJSDLzMRKKSU1LbE0p0S3uChZQb04NSdNXUG9NK84MS1VNzMvJzMvFcFPLUvMUVfQ0i%2FOT85OLYGqVrKuBQARLyRp#result) is an incorrect source. Also IPv4/IPv6 is not allowed by CSP spec as host-sources except 127.0.0.1, but Chrome and Firefox do support any IPv4.

Comment: @granty I wrote ":" because there is other project whose name is socket.

Comment: Anyway you miss `connect-src` directive name, it need to allow WebSocket() connect to external source. CSP should looks as `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; CONNECT-SRC wss://some_server.com/socket.io/ 'self'`. The `'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` tokens are not used in `connect-src`. Path name should be */socket.io/*, not */socket* - see err msg.